# Word for someone who loves to create and organise noisy, lively, chaotic events

Tags: single-word-requests

Some people love creating or fostering the creation of events that are noisy, chaotic and fun, such as parties, arguments, reunions, etc. Sometimes there's a negative connotation to this (like in provoking an argument), but sometimes there is not (like in organising a big, noisy party).

The word I'm looking for would be the English equivalent to the Spanish *armadanzas*, just in case this is helpful.

Any ideas?

Comment: Love this question.  I'm drawing a blank, but look forward to the answers.

Comment: I like the word *roisterer*, but that doesn't necessarily refer to the person organizing the event.

Comment: @drɱ65 δ: *Roisterer* is a bit like *wassailer*. Fine for Shakespeare, but I think today we'd more likely say [hell-raiser](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hell-raiser), for example.

Comment: I usually call them *annoying*.

Comment: The image that comes to my mind is Puck.

Comment: maybe something -monger, party-monger

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I quite like **hell-raiser**. The alternatives suggested here, like *roisterer, wassailer, merrymaker, carouser* and *reveller* all sound either dated or archaic to me.

For someone who isn't quite so "dangerously" boisterous, and not so closely associated with excess consumption of alcohol, there's always [a live wire](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/live+wire) *- a vivacious, alert, or energetic person*. And as @RSG points out, there's also [a party animal](http://www.english-slang.com/eng/more_expressions/party-animal).

Answer (score 7):

A **ring-leader** is the organizer of a circus (literally or figuratively).

An **instigator** is someone who tries to start an argument or other confrontation.

A **troll** is someone who picks a fight online.

A **cat herder** is someone who tries to control an uncontrollable situation.

If someone is the focus of attention and is motivating party-goers, they are **the life of the party**.

Answer (score 4):

A few words come to mind, but have too much of a negative or political connotation (*inciter*, *agitator*, *rabble-rouser*). The most neutral one I can think of is ***[firebrand](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/firebrand)***:

> 1. a piece of burning or glowing wood or other material
> 2. a person who causes unrest or is very energetic

It still has a slight negative bias, but to my ear is not as negative as inciter or agitator. The 'very energetic' component suggests an agent of chaos, but not necessarily in a negative way.

**Edit:** For a more positive connotation, you could describe the person as ***[Dionysian](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Dionysian)***:

> 1. of, pertaining to, or honoring Dionysus  or Bacchus.
> 2. recklessly uninhibited; unrestrained; undisciplined; frenzied;
>      orgiastic.

Dionysus knew how to throw a good party.

Comment: *firebrand* is normally positive, rather than neutral, but most metaphoric usages refer to people who are outspoken on large-scale political/cultural issues, and inspire/set the masses ablaze. Not exactly OP's 'party animal'. On the Greek side there's *Bacchanalian* as well, but they both imply drunken orgies to me (which may be what OP is thinking of anyway, for all I know).

Answer (score 3):

You could refer to that person as a *reveler*, where [*revel*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reveler) means:

> To engage in uproarious festivities; make merry.

The Oxford English Dictionary adds:

> A person who takes part in a revel or revelry; a person given to revelling; (hence) a person who leads a wild or disorderly life.

Answer (score 3):

Colloquially, the phrase **party animal** is exactly what you described.

Comment: Thanks, but party animal refers to anyone who loves to party rather than the person who creates or runs the show, which was my question.

Answer (score -2):

provocateur comes to mind as a one word instigator.